# SQL - how to get specific value of cell?

Tags: mysql, sql

Fist time using SQL and already confused.
I have a table :

```
A  |  B
--------
a  | 6
b  | 10
c  | 12
```

I want to filter it by using string comparison, but getting the value of the second column :

```
myNum = SELECT B WHERE A ='a'
```

At the end I want the value of myNum to be 6.

Just can't get it right... any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: but then I get the "cell" where 6 is in, I want the number itself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify table name.

```
SELECT B from table_name WHERE A = 'a';
```

Comment: Im sorry, didn't get it. what is the table name? My total includes one shit that has 2 columns , what table name should I use? and where here the number 6 is included?

Comment: as you mentioned you are having table, so run `show tables`, this will show you the tablename ..:)

Answer (score 0):

You need the table name.

`SELECT b FROM tablename WHERE A='a';`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to include the table name. Secondly, you need to use := for assignment and @ as a prefix to a variable:

```
Select 
    @myNum := B 
From 
    test 
Where 
    A = 'a';
```

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6cf0/2)</kbd>**

This will also return a result set. If you just want variable assignment, you can use `Select ... Into`

```
Select 
    B 
into 
    @myNum 
From 
    test 
Where 
    A = 'a'
```

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6cf0/3)</kbd>**

These assume your variable is within MySQL, if you are using a different programming language then there will a different method.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
Select B from test where A ='a';
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4136/3)